# How to set the culture info in unmanaged C++?

Tags: c++, windows, unmanaged, cultureinfo

I got a program written in unmanaged C++, I need to get the cultural info from the system and set that info to the current execution thread in my c++ application.

Thanks.

Comment: what operating system? (windows, i presume?)

Comment: you should also state that it is a windows specific question ;) I had to google in order to know what culture info is and I'm not sure every C++ dev knows it.

Comment: I apologize, you are right it is a windows application.

Comment: no worries. we just mentioned this to make sure you get the right answers from people.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In unmanaged C++ on windows, what you need is the Locale. Culture is a term defined in .NET, as a replacement for that term.

There's a whole host of functions, but the one where you need to start is called SetThreadLocale.

[SetThreadLocale Function (Windows) @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374051%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Within the documentation at MSDN, it appears that there are quirks in Vista. You may wish to consult the following function as well.

[SetThreadUILanguage Function (Windows) @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374053%28VS.85%29.aspx)

The other functions of interest are available here.

[National Language Support Functions (Windows) @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319081%28VS.85%29.aspx)
[Multilingual User Interface Functions (Windows) @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319074%28VS.85%29.aspx)

**edit:**

If you are developing an application with really basic support, setlocale() may also be of interest.

[setlocale (C/C++) @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e22ty2t%28VS.80%29.aspx)