# Getting current system language in Windows Phone 8 C++

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, localization

I'm porting a C++ game to Windows Phone 8. In iOS and Android I use the сurrent language name to select internal game resources (`en`, `de`, `es`, etc.). How I can get the current system language in Windows Phone 8 from C++?

For C# there is .NET solution with `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture`, but it's inaccessible from a C++ Windows Phone 8 application.

Comment: I'm not sure if your question is a dupe of this, but check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649676/c-win32-api-equivalent-of-cultureinfo-twoletterisolanguagename  and possibly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759612/how-to-set-the-culture-info-in-unmanaged-c

Comment: GetUserDefaultLocaleName: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dd318136(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Windows Phone 8 has following settings: "Phone language", "Country/Region", "Regional format". GetUserDefaultLocaleName returns "regional format", but all phone UI localization depends on "phone language".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `GetUserPreferredUILanguages` API for that.

[Here's a sample.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj244362%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes, this function returns current phone language in windows phone 8, thanks.